# Use a Username from a Deleted Trailhead Playground

Tags: username

I have a user that was on a Trailhead playground, i deleted the playground some time ago, and now i want to use a username name that was on that playground on a production org is possible?

Regards

Comment: I would recommend trying that, did you?

Comment: i try to see the documentation i have for the username that i had in that org, but i don't have it. For that reason i'm gonna contact the salesforce support to see if is a way to refresh that org. If not i have to wait the timeout time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove a Trailhead org from your account, it is not deleted immediately. Instead, it will sit around waiting for the timeout period for reclaiming inactive orgs (between six and twelve months, last I checked), and then eventually be freed up. You can log in to that org via the normal login page, assuming you have, or can recover, the password, then manually change the user name, or wait until the org is deleted in about a year. Support may be able to reset your password for you if you ask, but they can only do so if it would go to the email address on the user account. You can also try the normal password reset function available from the main login page.